# highslide refresh parent

Tags: highslide

Using Highslide I would like to refresh the parent page when I close a ajax window using the close X. I already have a button on the page that will do it but can't guarantee a user will use the button. I've tried a couple examples I've found but none seem to work.

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterClose = function() {
parent.window.location.reload();
}

hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterClose = function() {
if (this.a.id == 'tag-send-form') parent.window.location.reload();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Put this in a script block after the Highslide Javascript file (or in your highslide.config.js file):

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterClose = function() {
    window.location.reload();
};
```

**Note: This code requires highslide-full.js**